# Is it possible to "align" an element e.g input box, with % of screen in CSS for a form

Tags: css

I am trying to align the input boxes of a form so that they all line up under each other on the page. I was hoping to use `#FullNameText{text-align:15%;color:c0c0c0;}` in the CSS document for the following element

```
<p>
    <span Id="FullNameText">Full Name:</span>
    <input name="FullName" id="FullNameTab" autofocus="" onblur="fullNameCheck()" type="text">
</p>
```

The text-align:15% part has no effect on the page. Can % be used to align things?

Comment: you could put a width on the <input>. Such as input{width:15%}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#FullNameText { 
    width: 15%;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to text-align to %

text-align can only be left, right, center, justify, inherit

**update:**
you can give padding or margin to #FullNameText

Answer (score 0):

To associate elements together in a `form`, use `fieldset` rather than paragraph, and to associate a label with an `input`, use a `label` (with `for` attribute), this allows clicking on the `label` text to focus the element to which that text applies:

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="fullNameTab" id="FullNameText">Full Name:</label>
    <input name="FullName" id="FullNameTab" autofocus="" onblur="fullNameCheck()" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

Then you can specify `width` or `margin` on the `label` (as you could with the `span`, but this is a little more semantic and meaningful):

```
label {
    display: inline-block; /* to allow a specified width to be defined */
    width: 15%; /* adjust to taste */
    margin: 0 5% 0 10%; /* 0 margin-top, 5% margin-left, 0 margin-bottom,
                           10% margin-left */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F9Y7t/1/).

Comment: Nice One, using your Code

Answer (score 0):

no you can't use text-align with a % value.
If you want to align your input boxes exactly (presumably with their labels next to them) you could consider using floating divs.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="left label">Full Name:</div>
<div class="left content"><input name="FullName" id="FullNameTab" autofocus="" onblur="fullNameCheck()" type="text"> </div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left; 
}

.label{
width:30%;
}

.content{
width:70%
}
```